# Pre selection of checkboxes in angular-multi-select dropdown

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-dropdown-multiselect

I am using Angularjs Dropdown multiselect [from here](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main). I am implementing CRUD options using Angularjs and ASP.NET Web API. Its working perfectly fine in Create, but when I go to update I am not able to pre-select (checkboxes been checked) the values in multiselect drop down.

```js
 $scope.example8model = []; $scope.example8data = [ {id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"} ]; 
$scope.example8settings = { checkBoxes: true, };
```

```html
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example8data" selected-model="example8model" extra-settings="example8settings"></div>
```

Now, when I bind to `$scope.example8model = [{id: 1, label: "David"}]`, how should I make the checkboxes to be selected.

Purpose of doing this is because I want to implement it in Update functionality, where I have preselected data to be binded.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using `idProperty` setting in `extra-settings` attribute? (Something like `$scope.example8settings = { checkBoxes: true, idProperty: 'id'};`, to force the directive to compare options by property instead of by reference)

Comment: Yes it works and checks the checkboxes, but by default it checks all checkboxes instead of binded ones (selected-model="example8model").

Comment: Cay you please provide [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Since I can't reproduce your issue. Please take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/f5gn3q59/1/